# C# Get id of dynamically created labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I need to be able to set the IDs of dynamically generated labels instead of letting SharePoint prefix my labels with a long cryptic id of its own. Is this possible or is there another property of label that I can use as a unique identifier in a separate method?

```
Label animal = new Label();
animal.ID = cat;
```

The id for this label will be something like:
`ctl00_m_g_e0c173c0_edf3_4a99_a1dd_7bef33144c0b_ctl00_cat`

I need it to be cat.

Comment: Not a Sharepoint developer myself.. but surely the label has a ClientID? E.g: `animal.ClientID` == ctl00_m_g_e0c173c0_edf3_4a99_a1dd_7bef33144c0b_ctl00_cat. Why do you need it to be "cat" if the runtime provides a way to get the actual ID?

Comment: Because I need to know what the id will be on the label so I can use it in a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the client-side id to be the same as the server-side id, use:

```
animal.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the ClientId of a server control. It is a read only property.

The cryptic id you see is actually your control heirarchy.

Comment: So thats why I got a read only error when trying to set `animal.ClientID = "Static"`. Is there any way around this? Alternative to `ClientID`?

Comment: Are you trying to identify this control on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to access the control with javascript and are using jQuery, you can just the various regex selectors:

```
$("label[id$='cat']")
```

That will look for a label element with an id that ends with 'cat'

If your javascript is in the aspx file, and not a js file, you can also access it like so:

```
$('#<%=cat.ClientID %>')
```

That will just inject that long id created by Sharepoint into your js.  Key is it needs to reside in the aspx file, not a js file.